# Where to find play.core.SBTLink and SBTDocHandler classes in 2.3?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I am migrating from Play 2.2.2 to Play 2.3.4 and found that `play.core.SBTLink` and `play.core.SBTDocHandler` that were part of 2.2 are not available in 2.3.

I do not know what these classes are for nor can I isolate which library they belong to in the new Play 2.3 framework. The Play 2.3 migration guide doesn't mention these classes at all.

How can I resolve these classes? What library or plugin must I import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen these classes before, but a quick glance at [the repository of Play Framework at GitHub](https://github.com/playframework/playframework) revealed [BuildLink and BuildDocHandler](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/master/framework/src/build-link/src/main/java/play/core) that both look suspiciously similar to what you're after.

Comment: Yes, that is what I found as well.  Thanks!